# Category Chooser in system.xml

Tags: magento2

I'm Trying To Create Category Chooser in `etc/system.xml`

Is That Possible to **Create Category Chooser** in `system.xml` ?

[image]

Choose Like This

Comment: Hey there have you solved your problem i am doing same thing i have  added in system.cml but value is not saving

Comment: no..............

Comment: @User69, you have to name the file system.xml not system.cml

Comment: @Black if other way of multiselect available then it will useful for you? Or you want this multiselect only?

Comment: @RohanHapani, I want this multiselect from the screenshot only, I already have a normal one thx to the answer of VDC.

Comment: So, you have found solution or should I add other answer?

Comment: @RohanHapani, I don't have the solution yet. You can add an answer if you like.

Comment: You can try this in case if help to implement the same type of functionality: https://belvg.com/blog/a-category-chooser-in-magento-2-backend.html

Comment: Have you got any solution for your screen shot? @Black I want same category chooser.

Comment: @ZealousWeb, no, but the solution from Rohan is great too.

Comment: @ZealousWeb no but getting similar on this https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-how-to-add-multi-select-dropdown-in-system-configuration/

Comment: perfect solution not getting

Comment: Yes but i want to display category tree like parent , sub..... And according to Rohan's solution , it will display all categories directly. I want to display with it's parent first then want to display sub categories. I have already tried solution of Rohan

Answer (score 6):

You can follow this below steps to add multi select dropdown using chosen library :

Add this below code inside your **system.xml :**

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<!--
/**
 * Created By : Rohan Hapani
 */
-->
<field id="category_multiselect" translate="label" type="multiselect" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" sortOrder="10">
    <label>Category Multi Select Dropdown</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Category</source_model>
    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\MultiSelect</frontend_model>
    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
</field>
```

Then, create frontend model file **MultiSelect.php** to display multi select dropdown :

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/MultiSelect.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created By : Rohan Hapani
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

class MultiSelect extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{

    /**
     * Retrieve Element HTML fragment
     *
     * @param AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $script = " <script>
                require([
                    'jquery',
                    'chosen'
                ], function ($, chosen) {
                    $('#" . $element->getId() . "').chosen({
                        width: '100%',
                        placeholder_text: '" . __('Select Options') . "'
                    });
                    $('#" . $element->getId() . "_inherit').change(function() {

                        $('#" . $element->getId() . "').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
                          $('#" . $element->getId() . "').trigger('chosen:updated');
                    });
                })
            </script>";
        return parent::_getElementHtml($element) . $script;
    }
}
```

Create **Category.php** source model file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Source/

```
<?php
/**
 * Created By : Rohan Hapani
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Category implements ArrayInterface
{

    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param EavConfig $eavConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $optionArray = [];
        $arr = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                $optionArray[] = [
                    'value' => $value->getId(),
                    'label' => $value->getName(),
                ];
        }
        return $optionArray;
    }
}
```

Create **adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml** to add CSS

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Created By : Rohan Hapani
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/chosen/chosen.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Create **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js** file for add js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            chosen: 'Vendor_Module/js/chosen/chosen.jquery'
        }
    }
};
```

To Download chosen zip : [Click here](https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-how-to-add-multi-select-dropdown-in-system-configuration/)

Deploy and clean cache.

**Output :**

[image]

**Github :** [Click Here](https://github.com/RHapani/MultiSelectDropdown)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out tomorrow and report back :) Can you add a screenshot with the result?

Comment: I updated screenshot. Please check it.

Comment: Nice solution!! I will upvote it, but the bounty award goes to the user which shows how to build exactly the one like seen in the screenshot of the question. If no one is able to solve it, then the one with the best answer gets the award which is you so far.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it does not look like in your screenshot, but like in the screenshot of the answer of VDC. I also executed setup:di:compile and c:f

Comment: I moved the web folder from your .zip to `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml` now it works :) Unfortunatelly this was not made clear in your answer

Comment: I mentioned in my blog that's why i added blog link.

Comment: Could you upload the chosen code to github and link it here, in case when your blog post is not reachable anymore? You always have to put all relevant information in your post. Your blog might "die" someday and then a big part of your answer gets lost. It is not mentioned in your blog that we have to put the chosen web folder in view/adminhtml.

Comment: Dude, I already mentioned in my blog. Please the line in my blog after download link. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113816/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-black).

Comment: You don't understand the problem. What if your blog dies one day, huh? What are users doing then if half of your code is on your dead blog?

Comment: I added github link. You can download full module now :)

Comment: Mark as accept and bounty if it's fullfill requirement. So, it will useful for others :) Thanks

Comment: As already sayd, I will accept if the answer is matching the screenshot from the question, which is not the case with your solution. So I am still waiting until someone solves it and if not, then you will get the award at the end.

Comment: I give you the award, even though it does not met the requirements, but you gave the most helpful solution. Thx!

Comment: @Black Happy to help !! Happy Coding :) I will upload solution if i will do same solution.

Comment: Great one..worked perfectly..

Answer (score 3):

You need to update **system.xml** file with below category filed

```
<field id="categories" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="12" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Category</label>
    <source_model>Namespace\Yourmodule\Model\Config\Source\Category</source_model>
</field>
```

And now create this file `Category.php`

> Path: app/code/Namespace/Yourmodule/Model/Config/Source/

And add this code

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Yourmodule\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Category implements ArrayInterface
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false)
    {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        // select only active categories
        if ($isActive) {
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        }

        // select categories of certain level
        if ($level) {
            $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
        }

        // sort categories by some value
        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }

        // select certain number of categories
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        }

        return $collection;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $arr = $this->_toArray();
        $ret = [];

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
        {
            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    private function _toArray()
    {
        $categories = $this->getCategoryCollection(true, false, false, false);

        $catagoryList = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            $catagoryList[$category->getEntityId()] = __($this->_getParentName($category->getPath()) . $category->getName());
        }

        return $catagoryList;
    }

    private function _getParentName($path = '')
    {
        $parentName = '';
        $rootCats = array(1,2);

        $catTree = explode("/", $path);
        // Deleting category itself
        array_pop($catTree);

        if($catTree && (count($catTree) > count($rootCats)))
        {
            foreach ($catTree as $catId)
            {
                if(!in_array($catId, $rootCats))
                {
                    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
                    $categoryName = $category->getName();
                    $parentName .= $categoryName . ' -> ';
                }
            }
        }

        return $parentName;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I need in magento 2

Comment: OK then in your question file path should be etc/adminhtml/system.xml

Comment: OK I will update my answer

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: check updated question

Comment: @VDC, nice solution, but this is not exactly what the OP asked for, but its a start.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way ..

First you update below field i**n system.xml**

```
 <field id="categories" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" >
    <label>Categories</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Categories</source_model>
</field>
```

After create file **Categories.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Source/Categories.php

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;


class Categories implements ArrayInterface
{
    const ALL_CATEGORIES = 0;
    const SYSTEM_CATEGORY_ID = 1;
    const ROOT_LEVEL = 1;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Options getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $optionArray = [];
        $arr = $this->toArray();
        foreach ($arr as $value => $label) {
            $optionArray[] = [
                'value' => $value,
                'label' => $label
            ];
        }
        return $optionArray;
    }

    /**
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return $this->getChildren(self::SYSTEM_CATEGORY_ID, self::ROOT_LEVEL);
    }

    /**
     * @param $parentCategoryId
     * @param $level
     * @return array
     */
    private function getChildren($parentCategoryId, $level)
    {
        $options[self::ALL_CATEGORIES] = __('All Categories');
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('level', $level);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parentCategoryId);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
        $collection->setOrder('position', 'asc');

        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            if ($category->getLevel() > self::ROOT_LEVEL) {
                $options[$category->getId()] =
                    str_repeat(". ", max(0, ($category->getLevel() - 1) * 3)) . $category->getName();
            }
            if ($category->hasChildren()) {
                $options = array_replace($options, $this->getChildren($category->getId(), $category->getLevel() + 1));
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

And Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this still not looks like in the screenshot of the question.

Comment: @Black yes but working like charm and this type possible in admin menu and my code is standard code, this code is working all magento version

Comment: @Black this solution is helpful you ?

Comment: it is a start, but it does not fulfill the requirements

Answer (score 1):

Check this doc.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-secondary-uiselect.html

May be help for you.

Comment: Thx, but I expect a full answer with working code.